# Fetch single value for a record based on a condition on column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to group records in the ID column and check if any of the status is 1 then substitute the status as 'IN'. If I do not find the value 1 in status then I substitute the status as 'OUT'.

Original Table:

| ID | Status |
| --- | --- |
| ID_1 | 1 |
| ID_1 | 0 |
| ID_2 | 1 |
| ID_1 | 0 |
| ID_2 | 1 |
| ID_3 | 0 |
| ID_2 | 0 |
| ID_3 | 0 |

The final table should look like this

| ID | Status |
| --- | --- |
| ID_1 | IN |
| ID_2 | IN |
| ID_3 | OUT |

Let me know if someone can help :)

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Please add its tag to your question.

Comment: I am using MySQL. I have added the tag now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert 1,0 to IN,OUT and take the min of that (min because 'IN' is less than 'OUT'):

```
select id, min(case status when 1 then 'IN' else 'OUT' end) as status
from mytable
group by id
```

If mysql, it's slightly simpler:

```
select id, min(case status then 'IN' else 'OUT' end) as status
from mytable
group by id
```

because in mysql, 1 is true and 0 is false.

---

If column has values 'IN' and 'OUT' it becomes just:

```
select id, min(status)
from mytable
group by id
```

Comment: This seems correct. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Dennon I added a simple solution for  when column already has 'IN' and 'OUT'.

Comment: I see. This is what Yurify suggested and it works. Thanks :)

Comment: @Dennon no, this is different to what Yurify suggested. It may achieve the same result, but my SQL is simpler to read and code and executes faster.

Comment: actually true. I could achieve the exact result with your query. Much thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, CASE WHEN MAX(Status) = 1 THEN 'IN' 
ELSE 'OUT' END AS Status
FROM myTable
GROUP BY ID
```

based on coment

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.ID, COALESCE(b.Status, a.Status)
FROM myTable a LEFT JOIN myTable b ON a.ID = b.ID AND b.Status = 'IN'
```

Comment: This works. Thanks. What if I had IN or OUT in the original table rather than numeric values 0 and 1 ?

Comment: @Dennon I'm hazarding a guess on that change.

Comment: @Dennon simplified and tested

Comment: I am not familiar with COALESCE function. But the first query seems to work. Thanks

Comment: `case when max(case when X in (<values to keep>) then 1 else 0 end = 1 then 'Match' else 'No Match' end`